# Relative path for external actions in QTP test is not working with QC

Tags: qtp

In one of my QTP tests, I called an external action from other test in the same folder and provided relative path i.e. only test name while calling (`Test1` in below example)

When I saved these two tests to QC in Test Plan under a common folder, I see "missing" appended to external action in `Test2`. When I open this test in QTP, then nothing in missing Resources. I also removed external action and reset Folder path in `Run > Options > Folder` to QC path, again inserted the external action selecting from QC.
Still this issue exists. Please help me if anybody know how to resolve this issue.

```
ParentFolder
    Test1
       ReusableAction1.1
       ReusableAction1.2
    Test2
       ReusableAction2.1
       ReusableAction1.1{Test1}  ["Test1" - I used. Not "...\Test1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are generally used with reference to Current Execution Directory.

While running from local, the current directory is either the folder where the script is stored or temp folder. But when script is run from QC, the current execution directory is a folder (something like C:\\Temp\HP\TD####\) which changes for every run.

You can check the current execution directory by using **FileSystem** object or **WSH** object or **QTP's environment variables**.

**VBScript's FileSystem object:** 
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilseSystemObject") 
Msgbox "Current execution directory is - " & oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

**WSH Method:** 
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
Wscript.Echo objShell.CurrentDirectory

**QTP's Environment Variable:** 
Current_Directory = Environment.Value ("TestDir")

I don't see any other reason for relative paths not working.

If you have compelling reasons to run script from both local and QC and must use relative path, you can check QC connection and if connected to QC, use absolute path from QC Test Resources.

> Set qtApp = CreateObject(“QuickTest.Application”) 
>   If qtApp.TDConnection.IsConnected Then 
>   ' Use QC Test Resources path 
>   Else 
>   ' Use (relative) local path 
>   End If 
>   Set qtApp = Nothing

Also **QCUtil.IsConnected** will return True if QTP is connected to QC (connected means logged in and connected to a valid project).